# Change if-else statement into switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I am having trouble on how can I handle too much condition. Now I have 5 items to be filtered and planning to add some more, but as I add some items it increases the possible combination such as 1*2*3*4*5 combinations for 5 so when I have 10 items now , it will be 3 million combinations. On my current thread some recommend me to use switch but no idea how I will perform it to reduce the possible combination. Can anyone change my if-statement to switch or is there some other way I can handle these combinations. Here's my program

```
        // ALL filter selected
        for(int subloop=0; subloop<sSpecialty[loop].length; subloop++) {
        if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // RegAffil
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") 
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // Administration
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*") 
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // RoomAmbience
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // Tuition Fee
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // Specialty
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
                list.add(sList[loop]);  



            // regAffil and admin 0-1
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // regAffil and type 0-2
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // regaffil and ambience 0-3
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // reg afill and tuition 0-4
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // reg afill and specialty 0-5
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);


            // admin and type 1-2
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // admin and ambience 1-3
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // admin and tuition 1-4
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // admin and specialty 1-5
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
                            list.add(sList[loop]);



            // type and ambience 2-3
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // type and tuition  2-4
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // type and specialty 2-5
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);



            // ambience and tuition 3-4
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
            // ambience and specialty 3-5
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

            // tuition and specialty 4-5
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);


            // without specialty

        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                ) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
                && amountTF == 0
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

        } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
                && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
                && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
                && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                && thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);

        }


        // with specialty
     else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && amountTF == 0
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])
            ) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF == 0
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF == 0
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF == 0
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3])
            && amountTF == 0
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);

    } else if (sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0])
            && sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1])
            && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
            && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
            && sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4])) {
        list.add(sList[loop]);
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to post 300 lines of code to express the issue you are trying to solve? How is Android relevant here?

Comment: Sorry for posting the whole program, but that's the issue sir , because of too many if-statement my program now have 300+ lines of code, when I add more Filter as thisFilter[5] there would be thousands and I want to reduce it .

Comment: This sounds like a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe you can use [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)?

Comment: Maybe you should try creating a smaller form of your problem in a simple program. This may help you solve it yourself. It looks like you are doing `list.add(sList[loop]);` for most if not all conditions. Maybe you should test instead for cases in which you do not want to do `list.add(sList[loop]);`.

Comment: Maybe I should change my statement , sorry for posting the whole program. All I want to know is how can I change this into switch statement that can reduce the possible combination .

Comment: I'd guess that you are having this issue due to encoding everything in Strings. You probably need a more sophisticated class hierarchy , something along the Strategy pattern. But as @Turing85 suggested, it may be best for you to tell us what the actual goal is. I don't think case/switching may be of any help here (also because it's over Strings)

Comment: Besides, am I reading it wrong or are you doing the same operation (  list.add(sList[loop]); ) for all cases? Why do you even need to test them then?

Comment: I have a list of  arrays in another class and I want to filter them by using this program. I am fine with having 5 items but as I add more , the combination of my program will increase so how can I avoid it

Comment: First of all, you should really isolate every if condition into its own method to make it more readable. Second, you seem to be doing 'list.add(sList[loop])' for every condition, so what difference does it make which condition is satisfied???

Comment: Your code is too long and incomprehensible!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I see a lot of repeated statements in your ifs.

I would, in the first iteration of 'optimization' to put all the statements in variables like this:

```
boolean filterZero = thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
boolean adminLoop = sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1]);
boolean filterThree = thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*"); 
boolean filterFour = thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
```

Then convert it to something more readable like:

```
 else if (filterZero && adminLoop && filterThree && amountTF == 0 
          && filterFour) {
            list.add(sList[loop]);
}
```

Also, I would try to see if there is less case that you don't want to do `list.add(sList[loop]);` in that case, you could simplify your conditions.

If it's not the case, also check for conditions that comes together. For example, if `filterZero` and `filterThree` are always in the condition when used, then you can do a concatenation of them like this:

```
boolean filterZeroThree = thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*") 
                           && thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by extracting the individual conditions of your `ifs`. If I am correct, I found these ten conditions:

```
        boolean cond1 = sReg[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[0]);
        boolean cond2 = sAdmin[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[1]);
        boolean cond3 = sAmbience[loop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[3]);
        boolean cond4 = amountTF >= theTuitionFee;
        boolean cond5 = sSpecialty[loop][subloop].equalsIgnoreCase(thisFilter[4]);
        boolean cond6 = thisFilter[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
        boolean cond7 = thisFilter[3].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
        boolean cond8 = amountTF == 0;
        boolean cond9 = thisFilter[4].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
        boolean cond10 = thisFilter[0].equalsIgnoreCase("*");
```

(You better give meaningful names to those conditions)

For the `ifs` themselves, since they all boil down to `list.add(sList[loop])` you can try to simplify the boolean expression (given that you have more than 4 primitive inputs, I suggest the [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).

Also observe that some of the above conditions may be self-excluding (I don't know, for example, if `theTuitionFee` can be zero; if not, then `cond4` and `cond7` cannot be true simultaneously).